# Optimising for-loop with Numpy.tile: takes longer?

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, optimization, vectorization

I have got a function that takes an array, a position and a number k. The function creates all numbers from zero to k, and then uses those numbers as replacement of the element in position pos for k copies of the input array.

The vanilla for loop version is this:

```
def expand1(array,pos,k):
    res = []
    states = range(0,k)
    for state in states:
        aux = array.copy()
        aux[pos] = state
        res.append(aux)
    return(res)
```

and it takes around **770 ns ± 6.35 ns**

I am trying to optimise this using Numpy. My function re-write

```
def expand2(array,pos,k):
    aux = np.tile(array,(k,1))
    aux[:,pos] = np.arange(k)
    return aux
```

and this takes **6.26 µs ± 65.7 ns** which is significantly longer.

I was wondering about **experiences people may have when optimising python code** that e.g. clones an array several times and does a different thing to each copy.

Apologies in advance for any possible lack of etiquette. This is my first post here.

Thanks.

Comment: I get that expand2 is way faster. What did you exactly test to get those times?

Comment: What *is* `array`? Show us something runnable, where we don't have to fill in (guess) details ourselves.

Comment: Hey - I used %timeit on Jupyter

Comment: @user2357112 say array = [0,1,-1,0,1,1], k=2 and pos =2 as an example. Sorry for not making it clearer in the question.

Comment: @Sejkko: Yeah, that's not big enough for NumPy to help, especially when the input is a list instead of an array.

Comment: @user2357112 thing is that I have very large numbers of these smaller arrays (or NumPy lists if converted) to process. This is way I am seeking to optimise the code. Thank you.

Comment: Could you just give the exact testing code you are using, i.e. variables and function calls?

Comment: @sehifle  say array = [0,1,-1,0,1,1], k=2 and pos =2 as an example. Sorry for not making it clearer in the question. I have many vectors like this example and that is the reason why I am looking into the code's optimisation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using numpy often you pay a certain fixed overhead to gain a per item speedup. When benchmarking numpy snippets it is therefore important to consider different problem sizes.

Let's do this with your two functions and a third one I have written:

[image]

x axis is k, y axis is time

Focusing on expand1 and 2 first we see the typical picture. The loop has a higher per item cost (slope) but beats `np.tile` at small k because of the constant overhead (y intercept).

Turning to expand3, we can further see that by avoiding convenience functions such as `np.tile` we can significantly reduce the overhead.

Code:

```
import numpy as np

def expand1():
    res = []
    states = range(0,k)
    for state in states:
        aux = array.copy()
        aux[pos] = state
        res.append(aux)
    return res

def expand2():
    aux = np.tile(array,(k,1))
    aux[:,pos] = np.arange(k)
    return aux

def expand3():
    aux = np.empty((k, *array.shape), array.dtype)
    aux[...] = array
    aux[:, pos] = np.arange(k)
    return aux

array = np.random.randint(0, 100, 1000)
pos = 493

from timeit import repeat
T = []
for k in range(100):
    T.append([min(repeat(f, number=100)) for f in (expand1, expand2, expand3)])

import pylab
pylab.plot(T)
pylab.legend('expand1 expand2 expand3'.split())
pylab.show()
```

Comment: This is extremely useful. Thank you very much!